# django error validation datetime.datetime, tz format

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm trying to filter publications by date, with this code but try it, I get this error

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
data = Entry.objects.filter(date_publication=[from_date, datetime.now()])
```

[u"'[datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 18, 27, 9, 451000), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 17, 18, 27, 9, 451000)]' tiene un formato incorrecto. Debe ser del tipo YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]."]

```
class Productos(models.Model):
    ...
    date_publication =      models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        ...
```

help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
data = Entry.objects.filter(date_publication__gte=from_date, date_publication__lte=datetime.now())
```